# Cocos 2D is it possible to add more CCActions to a node during execution?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

I have a node in my game that I'd like to be able to queue up additional actions after it's already started executing.  Is this even a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify?  You can add actions to a sprite that is already performing actions.  If you're looking to run an action at a later time, you can use scheduleOnce; this will allow you to execute a method after a specified duration.

Comment: I'm looking to add additional actions to a sprite that is already running action.  i.e. animateUp, animateDown and then append animateLeft without a pause in animation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. Look into CCSequence (series of actions running in a sequence) and CCSpawn (spawn new actions, specifically useful when using a sequence).

The only thing you shouldn't do is to run two actions of the same kind at the same time. For example more than one CCMove* or CCTint* actions. This is because they'll override each other's changes, which will lead to strange behavior.

Comment: I'm already using CCSequence and CCSpawn to build up my actions.  What I'm looking to do is add additional items to the sequence of actions during its execution.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can modify the sequence when in progress, but you could add a 'CCCallXYZ' action to schedule 'one shot' a class method where you could take any action, including defining a new sequence of actions for your object. Timing and control could be tricky :)

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now and it looks pretty incredibad.  :/

Comment: hahaha ... incredibad !  yep , i just spent 2 days fixing a simple layered-cake sequence involving animations, no fun.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea, havent tried yet.
when you build your CCSequence as a last action put a CCCallBlock, inside the block you will have e machinism to get you additional action you added at runtime.
i'm writing pseudocode on the fly here.
the block appendend as an action would looks something like this:

```
{
     CCSequence *additionalActions = [MyRuntimeActionClass getAdditionalActionsForObject:spriteRunningTheAction];
     if(additionalActions)
          [spriteRunningTheAction runAction:additionalActions]
}
```

if we have stored additional actions for the object, we get the sequence and we run it.
additionalActions can store a Dictionary with key the address of the object to run on (spriteRunningTheAction) and value the CCSequence to append

Comment: The problem with this is that there's a delay between when the other actions end and when the new actions start (about 1 frame).